# Passing variable or parameter from Release pipeline to build pipeline in devops

Tags: parameters, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a release pipeline that triggers a build pipeline via the 'Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline' Task. I need to pass either parameters or variables to the target build pipeline. I've had no success with Release variables or the json parameter field in the task.

Has anyone got an example of how to pass either variables or parameters through to a build pipeline?